# Is OAuth1 possible with a Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-app, offlineapps

(I'm targeting Twitter which has chosen to keep it simple and use OAuth 1.0)

Is there any example of a Chrome (offline) packaged App using OAuth 1? I can see OAuth 2 is supported via the identity api, but all the examples of OAuth 1 seem to be for extensions which use tabs which are not supported in the packaged chrome apps. Also it seems you need to use chrome.runtime rather than chrome.extension with packaged apps.

Any pointers in the right direction would be welcome - I was expecting some prior art to be available.

Comment: Are you able to implement it anyway using HttpRequest API?

Comment: It is possible - I've managed it, should really tidy up the solution and put it out there for other people. One limitation though: I had to use webview to view the twitter sign-on page which while is supported for Mac/Win/*nix is not yet supported by the Chrome Cordova collaboration.